# Filter options on a Synchronized Object in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-synchronization

I need to limit the records that come into Marketing Cloud through object synchronization from Salescloud. I know you can limit records by date or boolean fields. Recently I added a new checkbox field on all the objects in Salescloud that I have synchronization setup for in Marketing Cloud. However, when I attempt to build out filtering options through Configure Synchronization, I do not see the field I want to filter on. I have 10 synchronized objects this is needed for and only 1 of the 10 allow me to do so at this time. What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Double check Field Level Security for each of the fields. Also, has your connector has time to do a sync before you try to select the field? Not sure if that is required but could be a factor.

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted, if it has been helpful

Answer (score 4):

Before you can use the field in your synchronisation filter, you need to add it to the fields being synchronised. In my example below, I would like to restrict the sync to contacts being PersonAccounts - but I am only able to use HasOptedOutOfEmail:
[image]
When checking the IsPersonAccount field, I see it is not selected for being synced to SFMC:
[image]
You need to enable the field:
[image]
Once you wait until the sync is completed, you can select it in your synchronisation filter:
[image]

If you are not able to select it in the list of fields being synced, you most probably have a permission issue in Sales Cloud, not allowing your integration user to read that particular field.